# Disable redis persistence in docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

According to [this](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/159) link, persistence of redis instances can be prevented by setting `--save ''`. However when I try to use that argument in my docker-compose.yml the redis instance still loads a database from disk and persists all data:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    command: ["redis-server", "--save"]  # disable persistence
    ports:
      - "7777:6379"
```

I also tried `command: ["redis-server", "--save", ""]` but the problem preserves.

How can I enforce non-persistence (empty redis on every restart)?

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you want to a) prevent Redis writing anything to disk as it runs, so it just runs from RAM, or b) you want to flush the entire contents of Redis at every restart. You can achieve a) in your Redis config file. You can achieve b) using @grapes answer, or using the CLI to run a `flushall`.

Comment: I want b) but only for one redis instance. In the same docker-compose file I have a second redis-instance that should be persisted

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not very elegant, but works:

```
  redis:
    image: "redis:5.0.3-alpine"
    command: [sh, -c, "rm -f /data/dump.rdb && redis-server"]  # disable persistence
```

`/data/dump.rdb` is where Redis stores the database.

Comment: A bit briefer: `command: sh -c "rm -f /data/dump.rdb && redis-server"`

Answer (score 13):

`--renew-anon-volumes` addresses the underlying problem of Redis retrieving a volume from the previous container after being stopped.

```
docker-compose up --renew-anon-volumes
```

Note that this affects other containers that keep their volumes around after being stopped, such as MySQL and Postgres.

Comment: This worked, as opposed to --force-recreate flag which did not. Can you explain please why in the world redis container ended up being persistable? Containers are said to be stateless, right? And I did not add any voulmes for /data dir of redis, all I did was  volumes:-./redis.conf:/redis.conf

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev Good question! The [redis Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/6ec0ad5628df2404509f776e9c70fbecf5364c10/5.0/alpine/Dockerfile#L72) actually creates an anonymous volume for you, which Docker Compose keeps track of unless you explicitly call [`docker-compose down --volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) or `docker-compose up --renew-anon-volumes`.

Answer (score 8):

For me work

```
command: redis-server --save "" --appendonly no
image: redis:alpine
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `--force-recreate` option for `docker-compose`. This just recreates all services containers from image every time, giving a guarantee that no data persists at all.

Useful for ci testing pipeline when you don't want to deal with individual flags for all services.

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: can I recreate a specific service? Because I have other services that should persist

Comment: yes you can recreate a specific service in `docker-compose up <servicename>`

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work for me. Maybe the setting only cares about building images, not removing containers?

Answer (score 2):

For me this works:

```
image: redis:4.0-alpine
command: [sh, -c, "rm -f /data/dump.rdb && redis-server --save ''"]
```